# Making a propertysheet as MDI child

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a class derived from `CPropertySheet` in my MDI application. It is a model-less property sheet shown when a button is pressed in one of the views of application. I need to make the sheet as a child view of the application
How to do it?

Comment: Another solution is to put `CTabCtrl` in child window, and add child dialogs to that window. You have to show/hide child dialogs based on tab index. Make sure child dialogs have `DS_CONTROL` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the parent of property sheet using `SetParent`, or when you instantiate the `CPropertySheet`-derived class object, you can  pass the parent `CWnd*` reference to constructor of `CPropertySheet`.

Is this not working?